# Read spark csv with empty values without converting to null

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Consider a csv:

```
Name,Color
Apple,""
```

```
 val df = spark.read
.option("header", "true")
.option("inferSchema", "true")
.option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls","false")
.csv(mycsv)
```

This still gives:

```
+--------+----------+
|Name    |Color     |
+--------+----------+
|   Apple|      null|
+--------+----------+
```

Expected was:

```
+--------+----------+
|Name    |Color     |
+--------+----------+
|   Apple|          |
+--------+----------+
```

Comment: then how will we read empty string as empty without having it as null

Comment: Sorry, I was confused.

Comment: Try `.option("nullValue", null)` instead.

Comment: Yes, it is getting empty now . Thanks @ernest_k

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, the option `"treatEmptyValuesAsNulls"` does not exist. See [the doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader) for more details. Two other options may be of interest to you though. `emptyValue` and `nullValue`. By default, they are both set to `""` but since the null value is possible for any type, it is tested before the empty value that is only possible for string type. Therefore, empty strings are interpreted as null values by default. If you set `nullValue` to anything but `""`, like `"null"` or `"none"`, empty strings will be read as empty strings and not as null values anymore.